# pySerial installed, but still getting ImportError

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, pydev, pyserial

I am new to Python, so I have likely done something obviously wrong, though despite my best efforts I cannot figure out what.

I am running windows 7 64bit.
I only have Python 3.5 (32 bit) installed.
I updated pip to the latest version succesfully and used it to install pySerial. I am working in eclipse oxygen with PyDev installed. My run configuration does show the appropriate path (as far as I can tell):

[run configuration in eclipse/PyDev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88Czw.png)

I have confirmed pySerial is installed by doing the following in python interpreter:

```
>>>help()
>>>modules
```

serial shows up in the list of modules.

also:

```
>>> import serial; print(serial.__file__)
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\serial\__init__.py
```

Additionally, trying to use serial in the terminal works fine, as below:

```
>>> import serial
>>> s=serial.Serial("COM4")
>>> s
Serial<id=0x383b750, open=True>(port='COM4', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stop
bits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
```

However, when I try to run the following code as a file:

```
import serial
print ("Test Script")
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\H260643\Desktop\Projects\EclipseWorkspace\CMP_Thous_Hr\Base.py", line 1, in <module>
    import serial
ImportError: No module named 'serial'
```

For what it's worth, the eclispe editor window has also flagged that line saying it is an "unresolved import: serial"

Answer (score 0):

Right after posting this I realized that the install path for python/pySerial did not match what was in my eclispe/PyDev run configuration. I corrected my run configuration and all is well.